# I want to redirect page with AntiForgeryToken (using window.loaction.href) MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I want to redirect my page using **window.location.href with AntiForgeryToken**.

My action is

```
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
      public action Test()
      {
        return view();
      }
    }
```

**JavaScript function**

```
    function CAllTest() {
       //Some condition check
       window.location.href = "Admin/Test";
    }
```

it is a admin portal. after authentication only im going to access my action methods. I want to redirect from JavaScript function.

Can anyone help about this

Comment: Why would you put `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on a GET method?

Comment: you show read this : http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/what-is-antiforgerytoken-and-why-do-i.html

Comment: it is a admin portal i want to use [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] for all my action methods.

Comment: then you cannot use `location.href` you need to use always `POST`

Comment: Refer also [this question/answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed)

Comment: i have a list that shows customers. when i click a customer i want to redirect that page to customer details page. any other way to redirect page from customer list to customer details

Comment: Why would you use javascript for this instead of just rendering an link? And why would you need `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on that method anyway?

Comment: @Prakash so you are just redirecting to a page from another ? and pass the token for all request from that page ?

Comment: can you explain how to send token